# VBA Run-Time error '424': Object required on Range-type variable

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting an 'Object Required' run-time error on my `ChoiceArr` variable. Code Below:

```vb
Sub wasp1()
    Dim Head1 As Range
    Dim now1 As Integer
    Dim ChoiceArr As Range

    now1 = Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    Set Head1 = Worksheets(1).Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToRight))

    Set ChoiceArr = Application.Transpose(Worksheets(1).Cells(1, WorksheetFunction.Match("Choice", Head1, 0)).Offset(1, 0).Resize(now1 - 1, 1))
```

I tried setting it as a variant but that didn't work either. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `I tried setting it as a variant` - did you also remove `Set` when you did that?

Answer (score 0):

### Array vs Object

- In VBA, the `Set` keyword is exclusively used for objects e.g. workbook, worksheet, range...etc. An array is not an object, so remove the `Set` keyword:

  ```
  Dim ChoiceArr As Variant

  ' ...

  ChoiceArr = Application.Transpose(Worksheets(1) _
      .Cells(1, WorksheetFunction.Match("Choice", Head1, 0)) _
      .Resize(now1 - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0))
  ```
- Here are some ideas and improvements so you don't end up empty-handed.

```vb
Sub wasp1()

    ' Reference the three main objects.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    ' Use `Application.Match` to easily test if a match was found.
    ' Note how to reference the header row ('rg.Rows(1)').
    Dim ColumnIndex As Variant:
    ColumnIndex = Application.Match("Choice", rg.Rows(1), 0)
    If IsError(ColumnIndex) Then
        MsgBox "The header was not found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Check if there is only one row in the range when the required
    ' rows count (without headers) would become 0 and later
    ' the `.Resize` would fail.
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count - 1
    If rCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No data found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Write the range values efficiently to a 2D one-based single-column array.
    ' Note the difference ('ReDim...') if there is only one data row (cell).
    Dim Choice() As Variant
    With rg.Columns(ColumnIndex).Resize(rCount).Offset(1)
        If rCount = 1 Then
            ReDim Choice(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Choice(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            Choice = .Value
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Loop through the elements (rows) of the array; note that it is one-based
    ' and don't forget to use its 2nd dimension which is 1 ('Choice(r, 1)').
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To rCount
        ' Do your thing, e.g. print to the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).
        If r <= 10 Then ' only the first 10 values
            Debug.Print Choice(r, 1)
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```